# HTML/CSS: Image Preview of Dish displayed in the same position, otherwise image is hidden

Tags: html, css, image, text

Let's say I have a list of Items

```
Item 1                 *****
Item 2                 *   *
Item 3                 *****
```

As I hover over these respective items, I would like to see all of their images appear in the same position (in this case the star box), otherwise it'll have a default image box.

How can I make it happen? I understand how to make images appear on hover but not on how to specifically position them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use JavaScript to that for you:

```js
$('#list').each(function(){
  $(this).find('li').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
      var itemText = $(this).text();
      $('#imageBox img').attr('src', 'https://placehold.it/' + itemText);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#list, #imageBox{
 width: 45%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 min-height: 200px;
 margin: 0;
}
#list{
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
#imageBox{
  background-color: #cdcdff;
}
#imageBox img{
 width: 350px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 25px auto; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>350x200</li>
  <li>300x250</li>
  <li>250x300</li>  
</ul>
<div id="imageBox">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very unspecific question, here you have 3 links, all need Javascript, one is simple, one is a bit hard and the last one is a true headache to me.

```
#main{border:grey 3px solid;
box-shadow:#000 5px 6px 3px;margin:0 auto;display:block;}
.imgStyle{height:100px;width:100px;border:2px solid silver;
box-shadow: 4px 5px 2px #000;margin-right:10px;}
#container{width:500px;margin:20px auto;}
```

The links go from easiest to hardest

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/YyvqVJ

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/xwzZKb

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB